# Using iterator to sum arrays in python

Tags: python, arrays, csv, numpy

i am using Numpy in python to read a csv file:

```
import numpy as np
import csv
from StringIO import StringIO
with open ('1250_12.csv','rb') as csvfile:
    data = np.genfromtxt(csvfile, dtype = None, delimiter = ',')
np.set_printoptions(threshold='nan'
```

which prints out the following:

```
[['x1' 'y1' 'z1' 'x2' 'y2' 'z2' 'cost']
 ['5720.44' '3070.94' '2642.19' '5797.82' '3061.01' '2576.29' '102.12']
 ['5720.44' '3070.94' '2642.19' '5809.75' '3023.6' '2597.81' '110.4']
 ['5861.54' '3029.08' '2742.36' '5981.23' '3021.52' '2720.47' '121.92']
 ['5861.54' '3029.08' '2742.36' '5955.36' '3012.95' '2686.28' '110.49']
```

so the first column belongs to 'x1', second column belongs to 'x2'...etc.  Lets say x1,y1,z1 is a vector represented in an array and the points underneath represents the value. As you can see there are mulitple points for each x1,y1...etc. Now i want to add up the points so that it becomes the sum of the vectors using an iterator. How do i use an iterator to sum up all the rows?

like this:

```
import numpy
a=numpy.array([0,1,2])
b=numpy.array([3,4,5])
a+b
array([3, 5, 7])
```

but this is only 2 arrays, what if there are hundreds then you would need an iterator instead of manually setting the arrays right?

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: Something got cut off in your pasted code.

Comment: lets say a = [x1,y1,z1] and b = [x2,y2,z2] and the sum is a+b but i want to use an iterator so i can process all rows.

Comment: Why use an iterator? This sounds like a job for something built around `np.sum` or the `sum` method of an `ndarray`. Explicit iteration tends to defeat the benefits of numpy.

Comment: im not trying to sum the points accross the columns like x1+y1+z1 im trying to sum up all the x1 points and all the y1 points...etc

Comment: Still sounds like a job for `np.sum`. It takes an optional `axis` argument representing which axis to sum over. Whenever you find yourself actually iterating over an ndarray, stop and look for a way to do it with vectorized builtins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have commented, there are probably ways to do this with built-in functions, but the following performs as you've described:

```py
sum = np.zeros(len(data[0]))

for vector in data[1:]:
    vector = map(float, vector)
    sum = np.add(vector, sum)
```

First, we initialize a blank `sum` vector equal to the width of the data matrix. Then, we iterate over the actual data vectors and add them to sum.

Comment: can you explain what this line: vector = np.asarray(map(float, vector)) does really quickly?

Comment: Sorry, that should just be `vector = map(float, vector)`! Anyway, because it's read in as text, we need to convert each element in `vector` from a string to float (e.g., from '0.5' to 0.5). `map(float, vector)` applies `float(x)` to every `x` in `vector`.

Answer (score 5):

Why not import skipping the first row?

```
data = np.genfromtxt('1250_12.csv', delimiter = ',', skip_header=1)
```

then

```
np.sum(data,axis=0)
```

Comment: @Andy this answer will give you a much higher performance since it avoids the `for` loop...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this in python one of the ways can be to iterate the list
Let's assume the input i.e. list of array is inp and the output array is stored in total

```
total = inp[1]
for eachRow in inp[2:]:
    for index, val in enumerate(eachRow):
        total[index] += eachRow[index]
```

Hope this helps :)